# How to perform Bulk Upsert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to perform a Bulk Upsert for documents. I understand this can't be done natively in `Meteor:Mongo` and that the Node MongoDB lib has to be used with `rawCollection` instead.

I have the following

```js
const bulkUpserts = [];
for (let doc of docs) {

  bulkUpserts.push({
    updateOne: {
      filter: {
        fizz: doc.buzz
      },
      update: doc,
      upsert: true,
      setOnInsert: {
        "foo": "bar",
        "createdBy": Meteor.userId(),
        "createdDate": new Date()
      }
    }
  });
}

Collection.rawCollection().bulkWrite(bulkUpserts);
```

The issue with ^ is that the `setOnInsert` doesn't seem to work. My `foo`s aren't being set. Looks like `setOnInsert` isn't available as an option for `updateOne`. What's the alternative though? I surprisingly cannot find a way to do this in Meteor yet.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used `bulkWrite` but I've been able to accomplish the task you describe using `updateMany` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/). Is that an option for you? If so then I can post an example.

Comment: Hey Christian, I've used bulkWrite perfectly fine in another Node App. But I ended up using what I have below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```js
const bulk = LineItems.rawCollection().initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

for (let doc of docs) {    
  bulk.find({
    fizz: doc.buzz
  }).upsert().updateOne({
    $set: doc,
    $setOnInsert: {
      _id: Random.id(),
      "foo": "bar",
      "createdBy": Meteor.userId(),
      "createdDate": new Date()
    }
  });
}
bulk.execute().then().catch(error => console.error(error));
```